# How would I let the user set a variable to be used in a line of code?

Tags: bash

So I have wanted to know if it was possible for a user to set a variable to be used in a code like:

```
Word 1="Example 1"
Word 2="example 2"

echo $Word 1 $Word 2
```

Then it would say

> Example 1 example 2

I know that this works

But I want to know if its possible to make it so the user of the script could be asked to input the value of `word 1` and `word 2` like this

```
what should word one be:  123

What should word two be : 456
```

Then it would plant the data in the code and the script would generate and run this command:

```
echo $Word 1 $Word 2
```

And it would say

```
123 456
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this [tag:ios]?

Comment: I'm write iOS code :-)

Comment: Have you ever written code for iOS? Have you followed the hello world for iOS...??

Comment: No I just started one day and learned by myself but some things like the read command I didn't know about instill now

Comment: Your code shouldn't work, as variable names cannot contain spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [`read`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html) built-in command.

#### Example:

```
% cat reading.bash 
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "what should word one be: "
read one
echo -n "what should word two be: "
read two
echo "${one} ${two}"
```

#### Running:

```
% ./reading.bash 
what should word one be: abc
what should word two be: xyz
abc xyz
```

Comment: Thanks that works great if you we're wondering I just wanted to make a easyer way to text through terminal it's pointless but I think it's cool and you cold send through ssh thanks again

Comment: I don't think it's pointless, I'm still confused as to the [tag:ios] relevance.

Comment: There is a jailbreak tweak called biteSMS it comes with a script that lets you text through mobile terminal but to send you have to type.  /Applications/biteSMS.app/biteSMS -send -carrier number here "text here"      But with the script I'm righting now all I will have to do is number:1231234567 text body: hi and it would put the two variables into that line of code above and make things a lot simpler. And I agree it's not pointless but some my think that side most the people I know think your hacking the government whenever the see a terminal window.  Thanks again for the help

Comment: @user2097755: OK, that makes more sense. I'll remove the tag because this question and its answer are entirely about the bash-side of things. Since you're new to StackOverflow (where many of us use the terminal and don't hack governments), let me point out that the best way of thanking somebody for answering your question is [by marking the answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq/#howtoask).

Comment: I will and here's the script

Comment: #!/bin/bash
echo "recipient:"
read recipient 
echo "message:"
read message
/Applications/biteSMS.app/biteSMS -send -carrier ${recipient} "${message}"
echo "message sent"

Comment: Glad I could help. You may want to quote both your variables because even the number may contain spaces: `/Applications/biteSMS.app/biteSMS -send -carrier "${recipient}" "${message}"`